# [mntent]: line 15 in /etc/fstab is bad while running sudo mount -o

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, ntfs-3g

Running sudo mount -o rw,remount /mnt/Data reports above error. 
Here is the fstab file

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=c8fd3429-3454-41df-ae9c-0f98615bc314 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
#UUID=1EF0-739E  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=47da3636-057c-4fb5-ab12-383d13d914c6 none            swap    sw              0       0
#Data
UUID=C06EDC746EDC6526 /mnt/Data ntfs-3g defaults auto umask=7770 0 1
UUID=1EF0-739E  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
```

Comment: UUID value need to be separated by "-". On Line 15, this is not the case. Hence the error. AFAIK

Comment: Maybe the question should be what I have done wrong than saying it is giving a error.... the options are usually separated by "," and not spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Each line in the /etc/fstab file contains the following fields separated by spaces or tabs:

```
file_system    dir    type    options    dump    pass
```

`options` must be separated with commas

Also, `auto` is referring to the file system type, so either you use auto instead of ntfs-3g, either you delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Line 15 is

```
UUID=C06EDC746EDC6526 /mnt/Data ntfs-3g defaults auto umask=7770 0 1
```

The different columns in /etc/fstab (separated by spaces in your case) are:

```
file_system    dir    type    options    dump    pass
```

So it looks like you have two more columns that required. For options, choose between defaults or auto and try removing umask=7770. So try:

```
UUID=C06EDC746EDC6526 /mnt/Data ntfs-3g defaults 0 1
```

or

```
UUID=C06EDC746EDC6526 /mnt/Data ntfs-3g auto 0 1
```

You may also want to separate the UID using "-", like the other UIDs in your file, if you above still doesn't fix it.